# Ho to create "nexus local user and role" in "sonatype nexus" using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I am working on an automation where I need to install sonatype nexus using ansible playbook, and create a nexus user and role.

So far I have installed sonatype nexus using playbook, and also I am able to login to the application and create a "nexus local user". However, I would like to automate the same thing of role and user creation (in nexus) using ansible playbook.

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think so there is any module that will directly create the user in sonatype nexus. you have to either use the api if available from nexus

Comment: true, yes there is a api available, i am making use of those. you can see it in below comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the `ansible-thoteam.nexus3-oss` role [on galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ansible-thoteam/nexus3-oss) or [on github](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss) which installs nexus3 and takes care of its provisioning. To be perfectly transparent, I am the current maintainer of this opensource role.

You will want to have a look at the [following groovy script to create users](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/files/groovy/setup_users_from_list.groovy) (pasted below as a full example):

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.transform.Field
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.role.RoleIdentifier
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.user.InvalidCredentialsException
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.user.UserManager
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.user.UserNotFoundException
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.user.User

List<Map<String, String>> actionDetails = []
@Field Map scriptResults = [changed: false, error: false]
scriptResults.put('action_details', actionDetails)
authManager = security.securitySystem.getAuthorizationManager(UserManager.DEFAULT_SOURCE)

def updateUser(userDef, currentResult) {
    User user = security.securitySystem.getUser(userDef.username)

    user.setFirstName(userDef.first_name)
    user.setLastName(userDef.last_name)
    user.setEmailAddress(userDef.email)

    if (user != security.securitySystem.getUser(userDef.username)) {
        security.securitySystem.updateUser(user)
        currentResult.put('status', 'updated')
        scriptResults['changed'] = true
    }

    Set<RoleIdentifier> existingRoles = user.getRoles()
    Set<RoleIdentifier> definedRoles = []
    userDef.roles.each { roleDef ->
        RoleIdentifier role = new RoleIdentifier("default", authManager.getRole(roleDef).roleId);
        definedRoles.add(role)
    }
    if (! existingRoles.equals(definedRoles)) {
        security.securitySystem.setUsersRoles(user.getUserId(), "default", definedRoles)
        currentResult.put('status', 'updated')
        scriptResults['changed'] = true
    }

    try {
        security.securitySystem.changePassword(userDef.username, userDef.password, userDef.password)
    } catch (InvalidCredentialsException ignored) {
        security.securitySystem.changePassword(userDef.username, userDef.password)
        currentResult.put('status', 'updated')
        scriptResults['changed'] = true
    }
    log.info("Updated user {}", userDef.username)
}

def addUser(userDef, currentResult) {
    try {
        security.addUser(userDef.username, userDef.first_name, userDef.last_name, userDef.email, true, userDef.password, userDef.roles)
        currentResult.put('status', 'updated')
        scriptResults['changed'] = true
        log.info("Created user {}", userDef.username)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        currentResult.put('status', 'error')
        currentResult.put('error_msg', e.toString())
        scriptResults['error'] = true
    }
}

def deleteUser(userDef, currentResult) {
    try {
        security.securitySystem.deleteUser(userDef.username, UserManager.DEFAULT_SOURCE)
        log.info("Deleted user {}", userDef.username)
        currentResult.put('status', 'deleted')
        scriptResults['changed'] = true
    } catch (UserNotFoundException ignored) {
        log.info("Delete user: user {} does not exist", userDef.username)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        currentResult.put('status', 'error')
        currentResult.put('error_msg', e.toString())
        scriptResults['error'] = true
    }
}

/* Main */

parsed_args = new JsonSlurper().parseText(args)

parsed_args.each { userDef ->

    state = userDef.get('state', 'present')

    Map<String, String> currentResult = [username: userDef.username, state: state]
    currentResult.put('status', 'no change')

    if (state == 'absent') {
        deleteUser(userDef, currentResult)
    } else {
        try {
            updateUser(userDef, currentResult)
        } catch (UserNotFoundException ignored) {
            addUser(userDef, currentResult)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            currentResult.put('status', 'error')
            currentResult.put('error_msg', e.toString())
            scriptResults['error'] = true
        }
    }

    scriptResults['action_details'].add(currentResult)
}

return JsonOutput.toJson(scriptResults)
```

This script is expecting to receive a list of users. You can refer to [README.md](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/README.md#users) as well as the [default vars](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/defaults/main.yml#L194) for details on the expected data structure which looks like this:

```
nexus_local_users: 
  - username: my_user
    first_name: my
    last_name: user
    email: my@user.com
    password: "s3cr3t"
    roles:
      - developers
```

I will not paste the full examples again but there is also a [groovy script](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/files/groovy/setup_roles_from_list.groovy) and a [data structure](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/defaults/main.yml#L185) for roles

You can have a look at the rest of the role for more information, more specifically the [tasks to declare the script in nexus](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/tasks/declare_script_each.yml) and to [call it with its parameters](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/tasks/call_script.yml)

Even if you don't want to use the full role, this is still in my opinion a good starting example to develop you own solution if you wish.

Hope it can help.

Comment: thank you so much @ Zeitounator, I started making use of this role from git hub repo. I find it very useful and i am making modifications to it to customize for my own use. one question, (this is out of curiosity) i have is that role a official page of nexus? because the files and code is very comprehensive and highly useful for all sorts of requirements.

Comment: This role has absolutely no relation with sonatype. As explained in the history/credit section of the README, It was forked from a [former role by savoir-faire-linux](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/ansible-nexus3-oss) after an announcement of end-of-maintenance. This former role previously had some [highlights on the sonatype blog](https://community.sonatype.com/t/nexus-repository-3-ansible-role/1256). As you will see the roles have totally diverged.

Comment: thank you, got it, the role you maintain is a master work.